# When I run ./AdobeAIRInstaller this huge exception occurs in terminal

Tags: adobe

```
$ ./AdobeAIRInstaller.bin: line 1: syntax error near unexpected 
token
```

(there are a lot of lines after it). I followed this [tutorial](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2013/07/install-adobe-air-linux-mint-32-64-bit/)

Comment: Please provide your OS & release details  (*architecture* may also be helpful; does it match the instructions implied in your provided example?)

Comment: Adobe AIR has transitioned into the hands of Harman and Adobe has set the link to redirect to an HTML page. so get gets the HTML page instead of the .bin file

Comment: The tutorial you used is close to ten years old. I'd highly advise you to look for more current one.  Also, Adobe has transferred AIR to another company years ago. I'm not sure whatever you're trying to do is even still possible.